# Clustering Mahout with Lucene on WIndows

Tags: lucene, cluster-analysis, mahout

I'm new using Mahout and Lucene. I looked at every forum and question asked but I cannot understand some things yet. I have my Lucene index done with TermVectors done. However I need to cluster that information using Mahout.

I have seen that everybody uses commands. The thing is that my project is being made with NetBeans on Windows enviroment. So when I see all that command-line expresiones, it's impossible to use them on the Windows terminal. Besides, I have seen that some people uses Hadoop but I don't get if will be useful for my app or not.

Can anybody help me how to use Mahout? Is it possible to import a jar library to my project and work with it directly from my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download and install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/). Then you will have the command-line you need to run the commands as given.